# Using a variable outside of forEach loop

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to java and I'm tinkering with forEach loops.

*I want to use entry.getValue() outside of the loop like this:*

```
hashmap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry<String,Double>comparingByValue())
    .limit(1).forEach(entry->
        {System.out.print("Worst output: " + entry.getValue() + ");}
    );
....//print the one iteration of previous loop, or use entry.getValue() as var
```

Comment: Just to be certain - you're looking for the lowest value in the map?

Comment: So what's the result of what you're already doing?

Comment: Result is the lowest value of a hashmap. im just looking to use entry.getValue() outside of the loop

Comment: You shouldn't sort, and should't limit, and shouldn't use forEach to find the minimum value. Instead, you should use min(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: @JB Nizet i wanna use my result outside of the forEach loop

Comment: I repeat: you shouldn't have any forEach loop. To find the min() value of a stream, use the min() method. Not sort() followed by limit() followed by forEach.

Comment: This looks like [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). @Heist you can't use variable outside of its declared scope (in this case lambda). So what you are asking is impossible. But you can use its value, for instance by returning it like in case of `min()` method already mentioned here.

Comment: @Heist when someone with 421870 reputation speaks, first of all *you listen*, and then, if you are sure you are not covered, you do *anything except* just repeating your statement. That's rude.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to `map` your entries to `double` and then use [`DoubleStream.min()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#min--) with something like,

```
double worst = hashmap.entrySet().stream()
        .mapToDouble(Map.Entry<String,Double>::getValue).min().getAsDouble();
System.out.println("Worst output: " + worst);
```

If you actually want the maximum value use [`max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#max--) instead of `min()`.

Comment: Can i get the corresponding key to that value, and put it in something like String w = ...

Comment: This will throw NoSuchElementException in the case of an empty map. The original code would simply not print anything.

Comment: You don’t need to map with `Map.Entry<String,Double>::getValue`, if you stream over `values()` rather than `entrySet()` in the first place. And if we don’t stream, the classical solution is as simple as `double worst = Collections.min(hashmap.values());`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the `max` method to get the highest value:

```
Double max = hashmap.values()
                    .stream()
                    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile

Comment: @Buhb stupid copy-paste mistake, thanks - edited and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something with the entire Map.Entry, and also elegantly handle empty maps, I suggest you do it with Optional.

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Double>> o = hashmap.entrySet().stream().min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
o.ifPresent(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue()));
```

This way, if there is at least one entry in the map, the lowest one is returned, and since it's wrapped in an optional, you can easily handle the empty case as well. In the sample code above, it will print both the key and the value, if it's present, or do nothing if it isn't.